# Error building app with cordova-plugin-fcm in ionic 1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-fcm

i am building ionic app,
for push notification, i have used cordova-plugin-fcm and all other code in fcm.js

but after installing plugin **cordova-plugin-fcm** i cant build android app anymore,

Error coming in ionic build android command

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
>   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0. required by project
>   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messeging:11.2.0. required by project

**FCM.js**

```
angular.module("home")
    .factory("FCM", function (APIService, userData, $state, $rootScope) {
            function initFCM() {
                    if (typeof (FCMPlugin) !== "undefined") {

                            FCMPlugin.getToken(function (token) {

                                    APIService.addFCMToken({
                                            tokenid: token,
                                            loginid: userData.login.login_id,
                                    }).then(function () {
                                            service.receivePush();
                                    })
                            }, function (error) {
                                    alert(error);
                            });
                            FCMPlugin.onTokenRefresh(function (token) {
                                    APIService.addFCMToken({
                                            tokenid: token,
                                            loginid: userData.login.login_id,
                                    }).then(function () {
                                            service.receivePush();
                                    })
                            });
                    } else {
                            //alert( 'admob plugin not ready' );
                    }
            }

            var service = {
                    initFCM: initFCM,
                    receivePush: function () {
                            FCMPlugin.onNotification(function (data) {

                                    if (data.wasTapped === false || data.wasTapped == undefined) {
                                            //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
                                            if (data.event == "1")
                                                    $rootScope.$broadcast("new-post", data);
                                            if (data.event == "4")
                                                    $rootScope.$broadcast("update-vote", data);
                                            if (data.event == "2")
                                                    $rootScope.$broadcast("update-like", data);
                                            if (data.event == "3")
                                                    $rootScope.$broadcast("update-comment", data);
                                            if (data.event == "5")
                                                    $rootScope.$broadcast("comment-like", data);
                                    } else {
                                            //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
                                            $state.go("single-post", { companyId: data.company_id, postId: data.post_id });
                                    }
                            });
                    },
                    subscribe: function (topic) {
                            FCMPlugin.subscribeToTopic(topic);
                    },
                    unsubscribe: function (topic) {
                            FCMPlugin.unsubscribeToTopic(topic);
                    }
            }
            return service;
    })
```

`ionic info` Output -

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3 
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1 
ios-deploy version: Not installed 
ios-sim version: Not installed 
OS: Windows 7 
Node Version: v8.1.4 
Xcode version: Not installed
```

> If i remove cordova-plugin-fcm app is working without any error

Comment: Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-**_messeging_**:
could this be a typo somewhere that is causing the issue?